# Security error when trying to use openDialog()

Tags: javascript, firefox, firefox-addon, firefox-addon-sdk

I working on developing a Firefox add-on using the `Add-on SDK.`
 I am trying to open the the window using `window.opendialog()` but it but it shows error  as 
`security error : operation is insecure.`
Code : 
`window.openDialog("http://w3schools.com");`
can you help me to resolve this.

Comment: Questions concerning problems with code you've written must describe the specific problem — and include valid code to reproduce it — in the question itself. See http://SSCCE.org for guidance.

Answer (score 0):

`window.openDialog()` can only be used from privileged code, not from a content script. Fact is, you don't *want* to use it - this function is only useful for XUL-based dialogs (the MDN documentation on it is very misleading), something you cannot have with the Add-on SDK. For HTML pages you should always use the standard `window.open()` approach however.

If you *really* wanted to open dialogs you could use [the low-level `window/utils` module](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/developers/docs/sdk/latest/modules/sdk/window/utils.html) to access a browser window from your main add-on code and to call `openDialog()` that way:

```
var utils = require("sdk/window/utils");
utils.getMostRecentBrowserWindow().openDialog(...);
```

Still, a content script cannot do that - it would have to message the extension and "ask" it to run that code.